# Walmart search API only show 10 results

Tags: json, api, walmart-api

I am trying to use Walmart open Search API to display a list of products from Walmart. If the user type in the thing they want, due to the API limitation

> Item results returned by the API are paginated, with upto 25 items
>   displayed per page (using the numItems parameter). It is possible to
>   request more by using the "start" parameter that specifies the first
>   item number in the response. Pagination is limited to the top 1000
>   items for a particular search

And this is their json:

```
{
query: "ipod",
sort: "relevance",
format: "json",
responseGroup: "base",
totalResults: 3570,
start: 1,
numItems: 10,
items: [
{
itemId: 15076191,
parentItemId: 15076191,
name: "Apple iPod Touch 4th Generation 32GB with Bonus Accessory Kit",
salePrice: 189,}}
```

I don't know how to start the displayed results from the start point 10 in IOS for tableView display? Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can simply add "&start=10" to your query string, which would give you the results starting at the 10th item.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It works perfectly. Many appreciations for your help! Have a great weekend